# Capturing server logs in Robot Framework

Tags: python, server, robotframework, error-logging

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to capture application server logs for failing test cases in the Robot Framework?

Historically this might have been a big ask (connecting to the host machine & extracting the data from the log file itself...) but my team has been making use of Scalyr recently and I was hoping someone may have had some experience extrapolating the data from that.

For reference, we're using an in-house tool that records all of our test runs, including full failure messages from Robot Framework if a test falls over. Ideally, I'd like to see the 3 most recent log entries from the point the test case fails, reported alongside the failure message. The application servers under test are hosted on ec2 or centos instances.

If I can provide any other info that might help prompt an answer to this, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

1. Install robotframework-requests and
2. perform the api call from RF.
3. When i see the Scalyr [doc](https://www.scalyr.com/help/api#log-query) , i see that there is Scalyr API where you can request for logs, all you need to do is use the below api to query the logs.

```
LOG QUERY
This method is used to retrieve events (log records). You can retrieve all events in a specified time range, or only events matching specific criteria.

URL
https://www.scalyr.com/api/query

Input
{
  "token":             "xxx",
  "queryType":         "log",
  "filter":            "...",
  "startTime":         "...",
  "endTime":           "...",
  "maxCount":          nnn,
  "pageMode":          "...",
  "columns":           "...",
  "continuationToken": "...",
  "priority":          "..."
}
token should be a "Read Logs" API token.
```